# updating value in list[i][j] and all of list[i] gets updated

Tags: python, list

I initialized an empty 2-dimensional list in python:

```
memories = []
for idx in range(x_size):
    memories.append([Dot(0,0)]*y_size)
```

where `Dot` is a class:

```
def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Afterwards, I fill the list `memories` with content, as follows:

```
memories[p.state.x][p.state.y].y += 1
```

The problem is that for some reason, the new value is updated not only in the single cell `memories[p.state.x][p.state.y]` but rather also in the whole row `memories[p.state.x]`. Why does this happen and how can I avoid it?

Thanks :)

Comment: `for i in memories[0]: print(id(i))` :P you have a list of pointers to the same list, not a list of lists.

Comment: Don't use `([Dot(0,0)]*y_size)` use `([Dot(0,0)]for _ in range(y_size))`. `([Dot(0,0)]*y_size)` creates y_size references to the same object

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - really?! But when I create an empty list, like: `a = [0]*size` - it creates a, well, a _real_ list, not references... unless I'm mistaken? Thanks anyway. I guess you're right, I'm just wondering about the reason.

Comment: ints are immutable, the above should also be `([Dot(0,0) for _ in range(y_size)])`